# Philips hue extension cable substitution

Tags: electrical

I have an outdoor Philip's hue light strip. The supplied cable is not long enough. They do sell extension cables for way too much money so I am wondering if I can just use ordinary low voltage wire and be ok. I would have to do some splicing because they have proprietary ends but that's ok.

Here is the transformer:

And the wire coming out of it (the DC part):
[image][image]

Comment: How much extra length are you going for? If it's a few feet, a bit of 18awg will be fine. If it's a lot, then you'll have to be concerned about voltage drop.

Comment: 50 ft. I would use 16awg wire anyway. Just wondering what that 105C on there is? The cable I got has "C(UL) Listed SPT-2W 2X1.31mm²(16AWG) VW-1 60℃ 300V" stamped on it.